# prove that in each 7-gon we can find at least two diagonal which the angels between them is less than 7 degrees.

Tags: geometry

prove that in each 7-gon we can find at least two diagonal which the angels between them is less than 7 degrees.

this is hard question for me, I couldn't find a good plan to solve.

it will be great if you help me about it. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reduction to the absurd ?

Comment: no, I have not tried. thanks for the comment.

Comment: Is it required to be convex?

Comment: it is not mentioned in question, I suppose it is arbitrary.